# Send SMS in Journey Builder does NOT subscribe contacts to a keyword

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I've been seeing this issue as very much hit and miss.  Sometimes it'll behave as expected, other times (like now) it will not.

I have a journey set up - just a single step journey that sends an SMS.  See below for the configuration:
[image]

If my mobile number is NOT opted in, it doesn't matter what the circled setting is set to (either 'Only send to contacts that are subscribed' or 'subscribe all contacts to a keyword'), I never receive the SMS.  If I text VAXJOIN manually to the short code, THEN run this journey, I receive the SMS.

The use case for my client requires to automatically subscribe contacts to VAXJOIN, as indicated in the screenshot above.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Was the contact opted out of the keyword. JB will not reoptin to a keyword

Comment: INTERESTING!  Didn't know that.  So if someone manually texted STOP, JB will not opt them back in?  JB will only opt someone in to a keyword if they have not explicitly opted out?